# classe php Singleton do tipo thread

Tags: php, linux, apache, thread, multithreading

Tenho uma classe que faz acesso a camada service da minha aplicação.
Esta classe é uma singleton. Atraves do service, ela acessa os dados de forma uniforme, para que minha aplicação tenha o comportamento esperado.
O problema é que, eu vejo a necessidade da minha classe também ser uma thread.
Isso faz sentido para vocês ?
Obrigado

```
class envio_massa extends Thread {
// atributos
private static $instance = NULL;


// construtor
private static function __construct() {
    ;
}

// funções

// singleton
public static function get_instance() {
    // Já existe uma instância
    if (self::$instance == NULL) {
        self::$instance = new envio_campanha_service();
    }

    return self::$instance;
}

// Previne o uso de clone
private function __clone() {}
public function run() {...}
```

}

Comment: Essa classe thread faz o que? não faz muito sentido, é melhor vc fornecer mais detalhes, lembre que o PHP não trabalha com threads por padrão.

Comment: essa classe vai acessar dados de envio no banco, por isso o Singleton, e vai enviar os dados para os clientes, por isso threads.
Podem ser muitos envios simultâneos  e não quero deixar o processador ocioso.

Comment: E a thread? pq herdar ela?

Comment: Para poder explorar o paralelismo do processador, mas nesse caso, o singleton não vai permitir.

Comment: Seu objeto deixa de existir na memória após o termino da requisição do webserver. Por que se preocupar com tudo isso ?